# What is the benefits of overriding default object methods instead of adding new ones?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm learning about javaScript prototypes and how to change default methods.
I just can't see the benefits from that rather than adding new methods and by so avoiding the risk to mess things up.

Guess there is something I am missing?

Ps. I'm a newbie with coding.

Comment: So you ask "what's the point in overriding default methods?". I can't see how JavaScript fits here (is it only a background?).

Comment: Don't forget the third possibility that is to extend existing methods by adding new parameters that default to standard behavior. (expl : the standard Array.sort(function) could become Array.sort(function, useStableSort). if useStableSort is false... or undefined, you will just use the existing sort, otherwise you use your own stable sort method. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing new methods and overriding are two different things, one is not better than the over.

- If you write a new method, you will add a method to the Object. Third party app or other parts of your app should be aware of those new methods to use it and use the new features that comes with the new methods.
- If you overwrite a method, third party will still call the method the same way as before. But you could chose to change the way your method behave on the background, for example to do this in a more optimized way than the previous method, or use a different database, or anything. But your new method should keep the same behaviour as the previous one, so the change will be transparent for third party, ortherwise, you will mess things up.

Answer (score 1):

It's rather simple: You can't get people to call the new methods. They call the old ones and that won't change. So if you need to know when they call (so you can do something), your only chance is to override the existing method.

Of course, you must not break the existing method's contract - like with any contract, breaking it makes everyone unhappy (eventually even the guy who did it).

So yes, you need to be careful with that but there are plenty of occasions when it's the best tool. And yes, adding new methods is safer and more simple.

Comment: I think he means overriding a method on the prototype rather than on an actual object.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum If he knows why prototype exists in the first place then it is obvious?

Comment: @Aaron 'and more simple', from inheritance perspective it's not simpler to add new methods..

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I don't see how that matters in the context of my answer. If you override in the prototype or in an object, the dangers are pretty much the same (only the scope might be smaller in the second case).

Comment: @EugenHalca: But it's more simple from a developer's point of view. In theory, practice and theory are the same but in practice, they aren't.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, there is a risk that you will mess up. But have a look at this example: lets say that you have a class `Shape` wich has a defult method `.get_area` which is defined to raise an exception (there is no general way to calculate area). But if you have a subclass of `Shape` called `Square` then you already know how to calculate area. The same goes for `Circle`, etc. But each time you have to define a different function per shape type (i.e. per subclass).

Now if you have a collection of shapes and you want to calculate total area and you know that all of them are subclasses of `Shape` class, then you can simply do this:

```
var res = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
    res += collection[i].get_area();
}
```

Very simple. Actually you don't need to know anything about elements of `collection` as long as you know that they have `get_area` method (the name becomes important) which returns a number.

Of course at the end of the day it depends on what you are trying to achieve.